# sort mat table when select from dropdown list

Tags: angular, sorting, drop-down-menu, angular-material, mat-table

how to sort mat table when the select value from the dropdown list:
I have a table that contains "status, date" column, and drop-down list that contains all the column names 
I want to sort the table by values that contain column names

Comment: Can you show what you have tried for it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MatSort Header](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview) from Angulars Material Table and emit a [sortChange](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api) event.

> These headers should be contained within a parent element with the
> matSort directive, which will emit an matSortChange event when the
> user triggers sorting on the header.

E.g.:

```js
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  selectedColumn = 'name';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.changeSortedColumn();
  }

  changeSortedColumn() {
    const sortState: Sort = {active: this.selectedColumn, direction: 'asc'};
    this.sort.active = sortState.active;
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
    this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);    
  }
```

Together with your Material Table and a selectionBox:

```html
 <mat-select  [(value)]="selectedColumn" (selectionChange)="changeSortedColumn()">
```

Here is the depending working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sort-default-hwa9q2?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html).

Comment: the sort is not working (either from table column or from the list :( )

Comment: Where it is not working? The Stackblitz works fine. You have to share at least some parts of your code or a [minimal reproduciable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if anyone should help you ;-)

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers too

Comment: @Mona, possibly you forgot to import the MatSortModule in your NgModule. Having the MatSort in the component is not enough.